# Get the number of hours between time Period

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have run in a scenario where i need to find the total number of hours that falls on a current period. I Have a Time in and TimeOut datetime which i want to get the hours where the employee worked between 10pm-4am the following day. How would i get the output of hours worked.

I Created an Extension method like this:

```
 public static decimal GetNightDifferentialValue(this DailyTime dtr, Employee201 employee, PayrollSettings settings, IEnumerable<Holidays> holidays)
    {
        //know if the time out is greater than 10pm of the dtr
        //07-26-2016 14:00 - 07-27-2016 03:00
        //if time out i
        var days = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(dtr.TimeOut - dtr.TimeIn).TotalHours + 1)
            .Select(i => dtr.TimeIn.AddHours(i))
            .Where(date => !(date.Hour >= 22)).Count();
        return days* employee.Rate;

    }
```

my problem is in the Where Method how can i Filter the hours that only fall on my category

Comment: Is there Daylight Savings Time in the time zone where this code will be used?

Comment: No.. This setting is only for our country's setting

Comment: sorry, maybe I misunderstand.. do you want to know the total number of hours of the employees who worked starting at 10pm and ending at 4am following day, or the total number of hours of all employees that worked from 10pm and 4am independently from when they started and ended to work?

Comment: it is the total number of hours the employee work in a single day from 10pm-4am the following day or any that exceeds then but does not exceed 4am

Comment: ok, try the solution in the answer below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public static decimal GetNightDifferentialValue(this DailyTime dtr, Employee201 employee, PayrollSettings settings, IEnumerable<Holidays> holidays)
 {
    //know if the time out is greater than 10pm of the dtr
    //07-26-2016 14:00 - 07-27-2016 03:00
    //if time out i
    DateTime dayIn10pm = new DateTime(dtr.TimeIn.Year, dtr.TimeIn.Month, dtr.TimeIn.Day, 22, 0, 0);
    DateTime dayAfter04am = dayIn10pm.Add(new TimeSpan(6,0,0));

    var hours = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(dtr.TimeOut - dtr.TimeIn).TotalHours + 1)
               .Select(i => dtr.TimeIn.AddHours(i))
               .Where(date => (date > dayIn10pm && date <= dayAfter04am)).Count();
    return hours;

 }
```

Comment: this Answered my dilemma.. Pure linq and better than my own implementation but needs to edit the operator to be date > dayIn10pm

Answer (score 2):

I see the problem is only with filtering, I would suggest compare `Date` part to determine is it next `Date`, if it is next date Look for `TimeOfDay` to compare `Time`

```
var t = TimeSpan.ParseExact("04:00:00", @"hh\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var days = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(dtr.TimeOut - dtr.TimeIn).TotalHours + 1)
        .Select(i => dtr.TimeIn.AddHours(i))
        .Where(date => (date.Date == TimeOut.Date && date.TimeOfDay <= t)  || date.Hour >= 22)
        .Count();
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PqTeZG)

Comment: based on the demo it must not consider if it does not exceed or reach 4am but the output still count until 4am which must be until 11pm or only one hour but it will be a starting point

Comment: Is `4AM` inclusive or exclusive? if not inclusive we can change condition to `<`

Comment: it should be until 4am but if its is not reached or exceed on the timeOut it will be excluded

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
if (timeOut.Hour > 4)
{
    timeOut = timeOut.Date.AddHours(4);
}

if (timeIn.Hour < 22)
{
    timeIn = timeIn.Date.AddHours(22);
}

if (timeIn > timeOut)
{
    // No overnight time
    return 0;
}

var difference = timeOut - timeIn;

return difference.TotalHours;
```

Basically, we first normalize the dates:

- If the employee got here before 10PM, consider he was there at 10PM
- If the employee left after 4AM, consider he left at 4AM

From there, we just have to subtract the two dates, and handle the special case where the new `timeIn` is greater than the new `timeOut` (if, for instance, he worked from 2PM to 5PM). In which case it means there's no time between 10PM and 4AM, so we just return 0.

Note that this algorithm doesn't handle the case where the employee works more than 24 hours straight.

Comment: Yeah.. It in my DTR handling it will split out into different shifts.. Well if the employee is In at 14:00 and out at let say 00:00 it needs to check wether that timespan of in and out falls in 10pm-4am

Comment: Well, if that algorithm returns a positive number then it is

Comment: I will post another try introducing variables and pure linq

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void CalculateTotalHour(string dtstartTime, string dtendTime)
    {

            DateTime d1 = new DateTime();
            d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dtstartTime); DateTime d2 = new DateTime();
            d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(dtendTime);

            if (d1.Hour >= 12)
            {
                d1 = d1.AddDays(-1);
            }
            else if (d2.Hour >= 12)
            {
                d2 = d2.AddDays(1);
            }

          //  if (d2 < d1)
           //  MessageBox.Show("shift end time is lesser than shift start time", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
             TimeSpan ts = d2.Subtract(d1).Duration();
           // ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm")//total dur
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get what I want but is not that good looking solution here is my solution:

```
var timeIn = new DateTime(2016, 7, 25, 14, 0, 0);
        var timeOut = new DateTime(2016, 7, 26, 5, 0, 0);

        if ((timeOut.Date - timeIn.Date).TotalDays >= 1)
        {
            var hrs12to4am = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(timeOut - timeIn).TotalHours + 1)
                .Select(i => timeIn.AddHours(i)).Where(a => a.Hour < 4 && a.Date > timeIn).ToList();

            var hrsOverTen = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(timeOut - timeIn).TotalHours + 1)
                .Select(i => timeIn.AddHours(i)).Where(a => a.Hour > 22).ToList();

        }
        else
        {
            var hrsOverTen = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(timeOut - timeIn).TotalHours + 1)
                .Select(i => timeIn.AddHours(i)).Where(a => a.Hour > 22).ToList();
        }
```

here is the demo [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EURJPx#)

Answer (score -2):

i think this is your answer

```
int hours = (int)(dt2 - dt1).TotalHours;
```

Comment: Yeah also my sentiment. It is clear in my question but if it is still misleading kindly edit it